# how to open up a VF page in a new tab?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Really new to VF, but here's my VF page. the desired effect is that i want it opened up in a new tab in the same window.

```
 <apex:page standardController="myController__c"  extensions="myExtension" action="    {!actionJackson}">
</apex:page>
```

Comment: How it opens depends on where it's opened from. Are you opening the Visualforce page from a Salesforce Tab, a button, or from somewhere else?

Comment: Are you referring to a _new browser window_ or the _tabs within SFDC's Ui_?

Comment: the user clicks a button, which has that VF above attached to it. The action method returns a page refernce with the new URL to go to. I want that new page to open up in a new internet tab, rather than a  new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your overriding a standard VF page in SFDC your halfway there, it looks like your trying to reference a standard controller of a custom sObject called: 'myController__c', kind of a weird name for an object but if you want to import the standard controller use your objects name as the standardController.

If your custom sObject that you were trying to create a new VF page for was called: "myObject__c" than your page definition would look like:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="myobject__c" extensions="class1"></apex:page>
```

Now go (using the web-ui):

`Your Name->Setup->Create->Objects->myObject__c->Standard Buttons and Links->Edit 'View'` (lets say you wanted to replace the 'View')

Now choose to override with a *VisualForce Page* and select the name of your page from the drop down.

Now following the link to view a record in SFDC standard layouts will take you to the new custom vf page. The same goes for edit (if you override it).

Now all you have to do is follow the instructions on SFDC for using and extending the standard controller or standard list controller.